# How to show image in overCurrentContext view in the ViewController2.swift class?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

How to show image in overCurrentContext view in the `ViewController2`.swift class ? I am doing this correctly when i worked manually but not doing when i using this programmatically in swift.

`ViewController1.swift` code -

```
    @IBAction func btnImage(_ sender: Any)
        {
            let imageVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageVC") as! ImageVC
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imageVC, animated: true)
        }
```

`ViewController2.swift` code -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

    }
```

I want this background alpha 0.7 and using `.overCurrentContext`

Output -

[image: Ouput]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing your viewController, Instead you should present it with **modalPresentationStyle** `.overCurrentContext`. Do something like this:

```
@IBAction func btnImage(_ sender: Any)
    {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImageVC") as! ImageVC
    vc?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
    vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    vc?.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

For more information you can read more about [modalPresentationStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621355-modalpresentationstyle) in Apple Docs.

Comment: this will create the same problem

Comment: @CreativeStudy I just tested it! Works fine, Presents a viewController above current with 0.7 transparency.

Comment: @CreativeStudy ModalPresentation Works if you're presenting not pushing ViewControllers!

Comment: How to go back to previous view controller ?

Comment: @CreativeStudy `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Thanks for this support

Comment: @CreativeStudy Cheers! Happy Coding!!